# How should I bridge a reference to an item within a CFRelease'd collection?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Say I get a CFDictionary or a CFArray from a lower-level API, and want to keep just one of its items around in automatic reference counted Objective-C land. Something like:

```
NSString* value = nil;
CFDictionaryRef info = FrameworkCopySomeInfo();
value = (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(info, kFrameworkSomeKey);
CFRelease(info);
// BUG: presumably value is an invalid reference now!
```

What's the best pattern for something like this? If instead of calling `CFRelease` maybe I'll try `__bridge_transfer` then the info dictionary. But the [bridged casts documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts) says (emphasis mine):

> ARC will release the value [i.e. my info dictionary] at the end of the enclosing full-expression, **subject to the usual optimizations on local values**.

I'm worried that if my code looks like…

```
NSString* value = nil;
NSDictionary* info = (__bridged_transfer id)FrameworkCopySomeInfo();
value = [info objectForKey:(__bridge id)kFrameworkSomeKey];
// …no further reference to `info`, but `value` continues to be used
```

…then perhaps the compiler could release the `info` dictionary right after I obtain the `value` pointer. What's the cleanest (least casts, clutter) but still correct pattern here?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually easier to cast the collection to a foundation type instead.

```
NSDictionary *info = CFBridgingRelease(FrameworkCopySomeInfo());
NSString *value = info[kFrameworkSomeKey];
```

Relevant docs are here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html

Comment: But couldn't the compiler release `info` right after I get the reference to `value` out of it? This still seems to assume that the value gets a retain+autorelease, which is in contradiction to [The Get Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1) — seems like `value` has no owner once there are no more uses of `info`.

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting will automatically retain `value`.

Comment: @MaddTheSane Okay, that'd be nice. Could you share where that is documented?

Comment: This came across my feeds today: http://mjtsai.com/blog/2015/02/28/core-data-vs-arc/ It seems like a similar situation: a local getting released before end of scope because it is not referenced further. But you are saying the value itself will be retained by the scope?

Answer (score 1):

Items that are bridged, IIRC, are automatically retained when they are bridged, and released when they go out of scope. The retain count of the object returned by `CFDictionaryGetValue()` should be 1 (1 from the dictionary retaining it). After it goes through the bridge, it has a retain count of 2. When you call `CFRelease()` on the dictionary, the object is released because the dictionary is no longer holding onto it.

So the code would look like this:

```
NSString* value = nil;
CFDictionaryRef info = FrameworkCopySomeInfo();
value = (__bridge NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(info, kFrameworkSomeKey);
CFRelease(info);
```

Your second code example is perfectly valid, but you will need to cast the `kFrameworkSomeKey` if there isn't an NSString-type value:

```
value = [info objectForKey:(NSString*)kFrameworkSomeKey];
```

There's some preprocessor/compiler attribute that Apple uses to mark their own `CFStringRef`s as being ARC-safe. For me, I've had to do this to my custom `CFStringRef`s:

```
value = [info objectForKey:(__bridge NSString*)kFrameworkSomeKey];
```

Also, the Clang Static Analyzer is your friend: it can help you diagnose bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct, and also makes my intent clear to other readers of the code:

```
NSString* value = nil;
CFDictionaryRef info = FrameworkCopySomeInfo();
value = [(__bridge id)CFDictionaryGetValue(info, kFrameworkSomeKey) copy];
CFRelease(info);
NSLog(@"Still have the value: %@", value);
```

Happy for any other suggestions, though.